# Interface Compilation

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface, compilation

Quick question regarding interfaces in C#. I was wondering how exactly they are compiled and used assembly wise.

I imagine interfaces are not compiled into assembly. I imagine that the interface definitions are compiled into the class at compile time, so interfaces are essentially a high level language concept.

Could someone please tell me if I am correct/incorrect in thinking this? I came to this conclusion as I have read that interfaces are not instantiated, they are their own entity. On the other hand however, I have also read that they are reference types which confuses me as that would suggest that they are instantiated?

Many thanks.

Comment: *"I imagine interfaces are not compiled into assembly"* Sure they are, otherwise other assemblies wouldn't be able to use them. Even `internal` interfaces are in assemblies. They are not "baked" into a class at compile-time, otherwise they would possibly have no relation to other implementors. Think of an interface like a contract, you promise that the implementing class complies with the contract. The contract can be passed around and used as a proxy for the actual implementation.

Comment: Interfaces have no implementation so there won't be any MSIL in the assembly.  But it is still a type so it will appear in the metadata like any type.  Creating that metadata is certainly the job of a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just disassemble a small program containing just an interface:

```
public interface IFoo {
    void Foo();
}
```

And this is what I get out of that:

```
.class interface public auto ansi abstract IFoo {
    // method line 3
    .method public virtual hidebysig newslot abstract 
       instance default void Foo ()  cil managed 
    {
       // Method begins at RVA 0x0
    } // end of method IFoo::Foo
} // end of class IFoo
```

So, if by Assembly you mean MSIL, the answer would be yes, they are treated like classes.

Comment: Thank you :) I see. Just had a play around on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) and it seems that interfaces are compiled into classes. The difference between inheriting a class and inheriting an interface is that they are inherited using the 'extends' keyword for classes and the 'implement' keyword for interfaces. My understand now is that they are in fact compiled into classes, except that the language restricts instantiation on these classes.

Answer (score 4):

No interfaces are not instantiable (is that a word?), but they are "real types", you can have variables of interface type, and you can access this type information during runtime using reflection, so they do exists in the compiled assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces have to be converted into a binary. Once could argue that they should be compiled into a class, but that is incorrect, since an interface can be implemented by multiple classes. Imagine a case when you have a project where you have 20 types of trees implemented. Naturally, if you have an interface for Tree, which will be implemented by each class, then, if things would work as you think, then the same interface would be compiled into 20 classes. Now, imagine large projects with many interfaces, implemented by many classes. You will realize that this would mean a lot of resources wasted.